# How to override AutoConfiguration in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have followed the Spring example [Serving Mobile Web Content with Spring MVC](http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-mobile-web-content/) and got it working.

Now I would like to replace `greeting.html` with a simple static page (and replace Thymeleaf with a simpler view handler).

What is the easiest approach in this particular case?

I am new to Java, the probable solutions in web use `web.xml`, whereas this example does not use `web.xml` and it does not seem to be the recommended approach in Spring Boot documentation either. So, use @EnableAutoConfiguration with some overriding? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is put the static HTML file in a place where Spring Boot will automatically look for static resources. [This](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) part of the documentation provides all the details.

So for example you can place your `greeting.html` under `/src/main/resources/static/` and you will be able to access it at `http://localhost:8080/greeting.html` (that's if you have not configured a different port of the root path of the servlet context)

Comment: With Thymeleaf, I only get an error "Error resolving template "greeting.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers".

Comment: With the configuration I posted above, Thymeleaf should not be involved in the process at all. Can you update you question with your Spring configuration?

Comment: Also note that have specified a very specific location for the html file, that is different from where it was in the tutorial.

Comment: ... However, if I change Thymeleaf to Groovy, it works. Is it possible to make this work with Thymeleaf and how?

Comment: Can you show your Spring configuration? And possibly your `application.properties`

Comment: See [GitHub](https://github.com/masa67/spring-static-pages), v.0.1, The configuration is from the original Spring tutorial.

Comment: I checked out your project and it worked just fine as is! I suggest you do a clean-compile before running it

Comment: The problem is that you are using your controller in way that is not correct. When a Spring controller returns a String, Spring will look for a template with that name. Since one does not exist, that's way you are getting the error. If you hit `localhost:8080/greeting.html` you will get the correct file

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it, just to serve static pages, there is no need for an explicit Controller (on top of what is there by default). Updated v.1.0 in GitHub, just in case somebody looks at this discussion. Case closed.